# JsCarousel Slider Issue

Tags: php, jquery, slider

I am using **jsCarousel** slider for showing thumbnail images in horizontal direction.I have 8 thumb images and I want to show 5 thumb images while loading the page. When I click next icon the slider will scroll image one by one instead of showing next set all images.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#carouselv').jsCarousel({
          onthumbnailclick:function(src){},
          autoscroll:true,
          circular:true,
          masked:false,
          itemstodisplay:5,
          orientation:'h'
      });
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the option scroll to scroll the number of images like

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#carouselv').jsCarousel({
          onthumbnailclick:function(src){},
          autoscroll:true,
          circular:true,
          masked:false,
          itemstodisplay:5,
          orientation:'h',
          scroll:1
      });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I am sorry to say that your solution won't work. The scroll option only for jcarousel. But I am using jsCarousel. So it won't works.